# Hard time with factory method implementation in java

Tags: java, methods, factory

So, I have a class that represents a game board (4x4), each space is the face value of a die, represented internally by an arraylist. I'm supposed to implement factory methods to generate the board.

```
public class Board {
    static ArrayList<Die> board = new ArrayList<Die>();

    public static Board makeFixedBoard(DiceManager dice) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
            //add faces
        }
        return new Board();
    } 
}
```

However, I'm having a hard time understanding exactly how to implement the factory method. Here, my return is a new board, but that just creates a new empty board rather than the one I generated.

This is the die class

```
public class Die {
char[] faces = new char[6];
char facevalue;

public Die(char side1, char side2, char side3, char side4, char side5, char side6){
    faces[0] = side1;
    faces[1] = side2;
    faces[2] = side3;
    faces[3] = side4;
    faces[4] = side5;
    faces[5] = side6;

    facevalue = faces[0];
}

public void roll() {
    int roll = 0 + (int)(Math.random() * 6);
    facevalue = faces[roll];
}

public char getValue() {
    return facevalue;
}
```

Comment: please make your question more clear what you actually wanna do ?

Comment: This method within the board class is supposed to return a Board object that it builds in makeFixedBoard(). However, it is instead returning a blank board.

Comment: its returning a blank board because you have written return new Board() here it will create a new instance of the board and will return it to the calling method. if you want to return a filled board then you have to create your new instance somewhere above your for loop and then set the values

Comment: can you post your die class as well

Comment: Yeah but the point of the class is that there is no public constructor  to set the values with. The list is supposed to be assembled inside the method, and then a new board object with that list is returned.

Comment: I'll post my die class in a second

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to keep `board` as `static`.

```
private ArrayList<Die> board = new ArrayList<Die>();
public static Board makeFixedBoard(DiceManager dice) {
    Board boardInstance = new Board();
    for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
        //add faces
        boardInstance.board.add(die);
    }
    return boardInstance;
}
```

You first need to create instance of `Board` and then in the for loop add the `die` you create into the `boardInstance`, after all the `die` have been added, you `return` the created instance of the board to the caller.